# how to add a clear icon in Material-UI pickers inside of input

Tags: reactjs, datepicker, material-ui

I use [Date picker](https://material-ui-pickers.dev/demo/datepicker)
inside of picker is an option to set it clearable, but this option is only when the picker is open

[image]

maybe is possible to add custom button like this:

[image]

Or maybe instead of doing something custom, to use another picker with option of clear inside of input?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add `InputProps` with `endAdornment` key to your `DatePicker` component in order to customize the input element and add a custom icon like this:

```
InputProps={{
    endAdornment: (
      <div
        onClick={handleClear}
        style={{ marginRight: 20, cursor: "pointer" }}
      >
        <ClearIcon />
      </div>
    )
  }}
```

You can take a look at [this sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/date-picker-clear-leouz) for a live working example.

Answer (score 2):

But if you are using a most recent version of mui DatePicker(`@mui/x-date-pickers/DatePicker`), you should use slots props like:

```
const ClearableIconButton = () => {
    return (
      <>
        {props.value && (
          <IconButton onClick={() => props.handleChange(null)} edge="end">
            <Clear />
          </IconButton>
        )}
      </>
    );
  };
```

and now:

```
 <DatePicker
        value={props.value}
        onChange={(d) => {
          props.handleChange(d);
        }}
        label={props.label}
        slots={{
          openPickerButton: props.value ? ClearableIconButton : undefined,
        }}
      />
```

Comment: My pleasure. slots are most used now on mui DatePicker

Comment: I tried to do this but it didn't add the clear button in the input field. Am I doing something wrong

Answer (score 0):

If anyone is looking to solve this issue now, here is my solution for this, which works well and allows you to keep the calendar icon as well.

In the TextField used to render the date picker through its renderInput prop, use the params to render both your new icon and the previous one:

```
InputProps={{
    ...params.InputProps,
    endAdornment: (
        <Stack direction="row" alignItems="center" spacing={1}>
            <InputAdornment position="end">
                <IconButton onClick={() => handleChange(null)}>
                    <ClearIcon />
                </IconButton>
            </InputAdornment>

            {params.InputProps.endAdornment}
        </Stack>
    )
}}
```